# Angular Unit Test for Service injecting other Services

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular8

I've written Angular tests before, but I'm at a loss on how to create a test that covers the code for the following.  I'll include what I've wired up, but the tests are basic.

Here is the service file:

```
@Injectable()
export class HealthViewService {
    constructor(private readonly healthService: HealthService, private router: Router){}

    createNewPatient() {
       this.healthService.currentStatus = this.healthService.getInitialStatus();
       this.router.navigate('health/patient');
    }
}
```

And here's the spec file:

```
import {HealthViewService} from '<not showing pathway>';
import {HealthService} from '<not showing pathway again>';

const healthViewService = {
    createNewPatient: () => {}
}

const healthServiceStub = { currentStatus: () { return StatusTarget.Inbound; }}

let routerStub = { navigate: () => {} }

describe('HealthViewService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [{provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }, 
                       {provide: HealthService, useValue: healthServiceStub },
                       {provide: HealthViewService, useValue: healthViewService}]
        })
    });

    describe('createNewPatient', () => {
       it('it should route to patient page', () => {
           expect(healthViewService.createNewPatient).toBeTruthy();
       });
    });
});
```

The good news is this test passes, but it's not really a good test for code coverage.  My question is: Is there some way that I could properly mock up the router and watch where the router navigates too?  And can I spy on the HealthService to check values there as well?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing includes articles covering lots of different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems from your code:

- your spec file does not test your actual implementation of the `HealthViewService` class because you provide some kind of fake object `const healthViewService = { createNewPatient: () => {} }` as instance of the service
- you expect `healthViewService.createNewPatient` method to exist, which will always be true (you don't call the method)
- the router navigate method expect an array of string, not a string

Here are the fixes you may consider (I removed the `HealthService` part to give you a MWE)

```js
@Injectable()
export class HealthViewService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  createNewPatient() {
    this.router.navigate(["health", "patient"]);
  }
}
```

and the corresponding spec file

```js
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HealthViewService } from "./health-view-service.service";

describe("HealthViewServiceService", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        // provide the actual implementation you want to test
        // shortcut for {provide: HealthViewService, useClass: HealthViewService}
        HealthViewService,
        // provide a mocked Router, injected through inversion of control mechanism offered by angular
        { provide: Router, useValue: { navigate: () => {} } },
      ],
    });
  });

  it("createNewPatient() should navigate to health/patient", () => {
    const service = TestBed.inject(HealthViewService);
    const router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    const spy = spyOn(router, "navigate");

    service.createNewPatient();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["health", "patient"]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Note: this is for angular 11. For angular 8, you may need to replace `TestBed.inject` by `TestBed.get`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for!  Thank you!